# Android - google plus login's ConnectionResult is stored in SharedPreference in the form of json string.How to get it back?

Tags: android, json, google-api, gson

I am use google+ api for login and i want to save the ConnectionResult object of first time login because when we navigate through the Activities it become null and application is forced to close.

This function store the result in shared Preferences.

```
    @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(
                    ConnectionResult.class, new MyTypeAdapter<ConnectionResult>())
                    .create();
            String json = gson.toJson(result);
            prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
            prefsEditor.commit();

            if (!result.hasResolution()) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                        0).show();
                return;
            }

            this.mConnectionResult = result;

            if (!mIntentInProgress) {
                // store mConnectionResult
                Constants.connectionResult = result;
                mConnectionResult = result;
                if (signedInUser) {
                    resolveSignInError();
                }

            }
        }
```

This function get the stored object and casted to required object i.e **ConnectionResult**

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

            gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(
                    ConnectionResult.class,
                    new MyTypeAdapter<ConnectionResult>()).create();

            String json = mPrefs.getString("MyObject", "");
            ConnectionResult obj = gson.fromJson(json, ConnectionResult.class);
            Constants.connectionResult = obj;


        signedInUser = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        getProfileInformation();

    }
```

String json= "ConnectionResult{statusCode\u003dSIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution\u003dPendingIntent{4135c520: android.os.BinderProxy@4135c4c0}}"

but `ConnectionResult obj = gson.fromJson(json, ConnectionResult.class);`  return null.

Please help me.

Comment: what you want back username,userid,email-id??

Comment: ConnectionResult contains errorcode and resolution .i want whole object again as it is.